# New lines appearing in text file when they are not supposed to be

Tags: powershell, csv, foreach

I'm trying to read out a CSV file, which contains userid, given name, surname and the sex of some users. The script should read out the userID and check if a directory with this ID already exists, if not it creates one. Than it should read out, which sex the user has. With this information the scripts makes a text file which contains a proper salutation and a static body text, that is the same for men and women. This is what I have accomplished so far:

```psh
#Variables

$script:pgm="welcome"
$script:log="$PSScriptRoot\$pgm.log"        
$script:csv="$pgm.csv"
$script:dir="D:\ps\users"
$script:txt="$pgm.txt"
$script:fix="$pgm.fix"    # fix is the file with the static text
$script:mrs="Dear Mrs."
$script:mr="Dear Mr."

# Create directories & textfiles

$imp=import-csv $csv -Delimiter ";" -Encoding UTF8
$users=$imp[0..2].Userid
$sex=$imp[0..2].Sex
$sirname=$imp[0..2].SirName
$f=cat $fix

foreach($a in $users) {
    if(! (Test-Path $dir\$a)) {
        New-Item -Path $dir\$a -ItemType Directory      
    }
}
foreach($d in $sex) {
    if ($d -eq "F") {
        foreach($name in $sirname) {
            write-output $mrs $name"," | out-file $dir\$a\$txt 
        }
    }   
    Else {
        foreach($name in $sirname) {
            write-output $mr $name"," | out-file $dir\$a\$txt
        }   
    }
    write-output $f >> $dir\$a\$txt
}
```

I have two struggles:

1. The script always writes "Jones" as name in the text file and ignores the other two and also only writes 'Dear Mr.' (also to female users).
2. The script is putting the name in a separate line. `Write-Host -NoNewLine` works fine for this problem, but only in the console, you can't pipe that into a file. Is there a way to do it with `write-output`?

The output textfile looks like this:

```
Dear Mr.  
Jones,
welcome to our company!

Your sysadmin
```

But it should look like this:

```
Dear Mr. Jones,
welcome to our company!

Your sysadmin
```

The CSV file:

```
Userid;GivenName;SirName;Sex 
JACKS;Tom;Jackson;M 
MILLE;Kate;Miller;F
JONES;Paul;Jones;M
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Write-Output just writes to the pipeline. Usually those objects will then become separate lines when written to the host or a file. The answers below show much simpler apporaches you can use, but your initial problem stems from not understanding what the cmdlet you are using does.

Comment: @Joey Sorry I'm new to scripting and powershell and still learning.

Answer (score 1):

no need to over complicate !

```
$csv=Import-Csv users.csv -Delimiter ';' 
$csv |%{                                                                                       
    if ($_.Sex -eq 'M') {$prefix = 'Mr.'}                                                     
    else{$prefix='Mrs.'}                                                                      
    echo "Dear $prefix $($_.SirName)" |out-file -filepath "c:\temp\$($_.userid)welcome.txt"   
    get-content $fix |out-file "c:\temp\$($_.userid)welcome.txt" -Append                  
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you should use a matched record as a source, instead of splitting data into several unlinked variables:

```
foreach($user in $imp) {...}
```

Once inside, you can call `$user.sex` and other CSV fields to determine the required parameters of a user. This will make the email generation code into this:

```
foreach ($user in $imp) {
    $title=('Mr.','Mrs.')[$user.sex -eq 'F'] # returns 'Mr.' if there's not 'F' in sex
    @"
    Dear $title $($user.surname)!
    Welcome to our company!

    Your sysadmin.
    "@ # a multilined string with placeholders for variables
} # that's all, folks
```

Comment: Thanks that helped me, but how can I output this in 3 seperate textfiles, each in his own directory, that was created in his part: `foreach($a in $users) {
    if(! (Test-Path $dir\$a)) {
        New-Item -Path $dir\$a -ItemType Directory      
    }
}`

Comment: I don't think this would work as coded since you will get an error if there is _any_ whitespace before the `"@`. It would be easier to get that out of the loop and maybe use the formatting operator to populate the here string. Love the way you access the title btw

Comment: Could you give me an example for that? I'm new to scripting and powershell and struggling a little bit right now.